# What would fungal technology look like?

Tags: technology, alternate-reality, fungi

In a setting I've created it's modern Earth just like you see around you every day except there's an area deep underground reminiscent of D&D's Underdark or Skyrim's Blackreach in that it's a massive expanse comprised of numerous tunnels and caverns with alot of unusual stuff in it that can't be found elsewhere. This area is primarily populated by Fungi, including a few different varieties of intelligent mobile fungi on par with humans. Unlike on the surface where they're regarded as myth and fantasy, magic and psionics are a bit more common in this underground area. Humans haven't discovered this place yet and the fungus people have never been to the surface and don't have any idea what's up there. All of their knowledge and technology was discovered and invented by them without the influence of the surface world.

I've already worked out much of how the varieties of fungus people themselves function and what level of technology each has, but I'm at a loss for what that technology would actually look like, what it would be made of and how it would function. The primary group of fungus people in the setting have reached the same level of technology as modern humans. They would have things like television, cellphones, computers and internet though separate from that of humans. What would a cellphone made by a sentient humanoid fungus that lives underground look like? What would it even be made of? How would it work deep underground when I can't even get mine to work when I'm in my basement?

Things like that. I really don't like hand-waving everything with magic; I've already learned far more about fungi than I ever wanted to in order to create these fungus people. I'd like something as scientifically plausible as possible with as little dismissal as magic that can be managed.

From the Comments:

> I think perhaps it's just my wording that's causing confusion here.
> Because you clearly still don't know what I'm asking for.
> Unfortunately I don't know how to word it in any other way to properly
> communicate the question in a way that won't be misunderstood. As far
> as I can see I've provided all the relevant details about form and
> function of the creatures and I'm not asking for a "a library of
> information", just about a few things which I specifically mentioned.
> The only difference between phones and computers these days is their
> size and the internet is an inherent part of them. **It's all the same
> thing.** And it's *one multifaceted question*, not *multiple
> questions*. What something is made of determines how it works which
> determines what it looks like. Thus to answer the question of what
> something would look like you need to answer how it works and what
> it's made of. All one question. I would never ask anybody to do all
> the creative work for me. I prefer to do it myself. Otherwise it
> wouldn't really be mine, would it? I just need help with this one
> question about fairly common technology. This answer to this one
> question gives me one example to use as a baseline for me to figure
> the rest of it out myself.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143049/discussion-on-question-by-demon-what-would-fungal-technology-look-like); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

It would all be reliant on [the Mycorrhizal network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhizal_network)

There's an underground network of hyphae of mycorrhizal fungi. This one can pass nervous signals down. Fungus people can join their nervous system to the network and see and feel what others feel. TV, mobile phones, computers, it's all about sharing a nervous system with fungi.

Comment: Also, everyone is blue, tribal and the story is extremely predictable. This is offset by the incredible 3D graphics it has.

Comment: @Demigan Popcorn movies are the spice of life my friend! Along with *Avatar* they include *Godzilla* (1998), *Pacific Rim,* *Monty Python and the Holy Grail,* and a host of others. Never dismiss the value of a good popcorn movie.

Comment: @JBH A good popcorn movie like Pacific Rim is absolutely good and deserves a place in the media, but I would make a distinction between popcorn movies designed to be one (which Pacific Rim might not be) and movies that wanted to be more. Avatar was supposed to become an entire Franchise like Star Wars but as far as I’m aware failed at it. There is I think a small cult following that watches it, but without the big screen and 3D it loses most of its watchable qualities.

Comment: @Demigan Ah-hah. Methinks we're all talking about two different moves. Nepe and I are talking about James Cameron's *[Avatar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_5)* (2009) and I suspect you're talking about M. Night Shyamalan's *[The Last Airbender](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0938283/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3)* (2010). The former is [ranked #15 on the top-grossing films of all time](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross_adjusted/?adjust_gross_to=2019) where *The Last Airbender* ranked only #838. I agree, it's still a popcorn movie, but it's no *Avatar.*

Comment: @Demigan BTW, part of why I arrived at that conclusion is the release of *[Avatar:The Way of Water](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1630029/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_2)* (2022), which breaks the failed-to-become-a-franchise mold and with a current gross box office in the multiple billions, it might rank #1 on the all-time gross list, which means its predecessor doesn't have a small cult following.

Comment: @JBH I was talking about Avatar but my apologies, I was unaware that high grossing changed a predictable story into an unpredictable masterpiece. My point was that the 3D+worldbuilding visuals were the main selling point of Avatar and best viewed in cinema rather than TV. Also I just watched the second one half an hour ago and the plot can best be described as “lots of dumb” but the visuals and surprisingly the character driven story are well worth the watch. With popcorn, because dumb plot.

Comment: @Demigan :-) Honestly, I thought you were talking about the Last Airbender. Avatar hasn't a small cult following. Quite the opposite. But you're entirely correct the story was predictable (even the "Bad Humans!" politics that drove it). I've not yet seen the second movie - but I'm willing to believe popcorn will be required.